# Check if current product page is a variant or not in Shopify

Tags: shopify

When you have a page like domain.com/products/product_name?variant=variant_id

This means that the page that is being loaded is the variant of the specific product (product_name) here since there's the url query "variant".

Like for example, 1 tshirt has many variant colors, so the same design can have different variant pages (this is just a simple example)
I want to check if the current page is a variant of a product or not before it loads through liquid. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `product.selected_variant` that will return the variant ID if the get parameter is present or not.

Based on that you will be able to write a simple if:

```
{%- if product.selected_variant -%}

{%- else -%}

{%- endif -%}
```

Answer (score 1):

`product.selected_variant` returns the variant object.
To get the current variant id use `product.selected_variant.id`